# How to know the application layer protocol in TCP?

Tags: network-protocols, application-layer

I watched in wireshark that there's no dedicated field to identify the application layer protocol,but how does wireshark do that?

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark (libpcap) only knows the Ips, transport protocol (UDP/TCP) and the ports. With this info it try to decode the frames with a candidate protocol "decoder". Usually it make mistakes.
If you want more accurately protocol identification you have to use a deep packet inspection analyzer. more info http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection

Comment: Wireshark's [heuristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic#Computer_science) are pretty good for popular protocols

Comment: Yeah how does wireshark's heuristics work?Simply by port number is far from good...

Comment: @compile-fan, heuristics by definition are not perfect; port-numbers are fine for 80-90% of use cases... so that's a good heuristic by my definition.  If you want to make snarky comments about port-number heuristics, I will look forward to seeing your commits to improve them in the wireshark trunk.

Answer (score 0):

This [email list](http://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-dev/200808/msg00252.html) entry describes a bit about wireshark heuristics.

In short wireshark uses the port/protocol number as well as magic constants when available. The heuristics can also use special properties of the payload (in HTTP one could look for the strings GET/POST/... in the beginning of some traffic). The *dissectors* (as they are called) can also look at other packets in the traffic which is useful when some other application hi-jacks port 80, for instance [Skype does this every now and then](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA148/which-ports-need-to-be-open-to-use-skype-for-windows-desktop).